# Criar DataFrame a partir de listas com tamanhos diferentes, mantendo a correspondência entre os dados

Tags: python, lista, dataframe, dicionário, índices

Eu tenho listas de comprimentos diferentes com dados extraídos de um PDF.

Cada valor e código faz parte (está dentro) de uma nota respectiva:

```
cliente = ['12345','15432']
nota = ['21/0576750-3', '20/063859-1']
codigo = [86, 6052,5031,1038,1025]
valor = [100.45, 200.34, 450.10, 150.58, 42.30]
```

Quero transformar esses dados em um DataFrame como esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs: O desafio é conseguir criar relacionamentos um para muitos de forma a manter a correspondência entre os dados das linhas.

Tentei o seguinte código, mas a tabela perde a referência dos dados das linhas.

```
tabela = list(zip(cliente,nota,codigo,valor)
df = pd.DataFrame(tabela, columns = ['Cliente', 'Nota', 'Código','Valor'])
df.to_excel('d:/nome.xlsx', index=False)
```

Alguém poderia ajudar? Obrigado!

Comment: Consegue colocar o pdf de exemplo?

Comment: Imonferrari, cara, consegui resolver com a solução que postei abaixo. Muito obrigado pela sua atenção!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Galera, consegui resolver a questão da criação do DataFrame sem perder a indexação das informações das colunas!

**A solução foi a utilização da biblioteca Collections - namedtuple**

Essa função permite a criação de uma tupla com itens que funcionam parecido com um dicionário, mantendo a relação entre as chaves e os valores extraídos.

Segue abaixo o código:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
from collections import namedtuple


formulario = namedtuple('Formulário', 'cliente nota codigo valor')


padraoCliente = re.compile('[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}\/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}')
padraoNota = re.compile('Número da nota')
padraoCodigoValor = re.compile('([0-9]{4})\s(\.?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*,[0-9]{2})')

extracao = ocr.getTexto('arquivo.pdf')

linha_items = []

for linha in extracao.split('\n'):
    if padraoCliente.match(linha):
        cliente = linha.split()
        cliente = ' '.join(cliente)

    if padraoNota.match(linha):
        nota = linha.split()
        

    linha = padraoCodigoValor.search(linha)
    if linha:
        codigo = linha.group(1)
        valor = linha.group(2)
        
        linha_items.append(formulario(cliente nota codigo valor))

df = df = pd.DataFrame(linha_items, columns=['Número do cliente','Número da Nota', 'Código do produto', 'Valor do Produto'])
```

Aprendi o procedimento assistindo a esse vídeo: [Youtube: Use Python to extract invoice lines from a semistructured PDF AP Report](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eTz3VZmNPSE)

Answer (score 1):

você pode fazer isso com o seguinte código:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Cliente': pd.Series(cliente), 'Nota': pd.Series(nota), 'Código': pd.Series(codigo), 'Valor': pd.Series(valor)})
```

Saída:

```
  Cliente          Nota  Código   Valor
0   12345  21/0576750-3      86  100.45
1   15432   20/063859-1    6052  200.34
2     NaN           NaN    5031  450.10
3     NaN           NaN    1038  150.58
4     NaN           NaN    1025   42.30
```

O único "problema" é que você vai ter que ver como vai lidar com a repetição do código do cliente e da nota.

Comment: Evilmaax, obrigado pela ideia! Muito interessante usar dicionários com Series nos campos de valor! O meu problema está realmente em manter a vinculação do cliente e nota com os respectivos códigos. Seria algo como um relacionamento um para muitos que eu ainda não consegui fazer na extração.

Comment: Cara, para isso eu pensei em algo bem rudimentar. Poderia percorrer a coluna de Nota e quando encontrasse alguma repetição na linha atual com a anterior, adicionaria o valor de cliente da linha anterior na linha atual. Dá pra fazer com for e if. Certamente tem uma solução mais Pythonica, mas vai resolver o problema

Comment: Cara, consegui resolver com a solução que postei acima. Muito obrigado por sua ajuda!!! Você me deu duas ótimas ideias para usar nos meus próximos códigos.

Comment: Boooa @Re_Moreira Sucesso, mano!